# Combination of two bivariate Gaussian covariance matrices

Tags: probability-distributions

I have measurements of 2 position vectors ($\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$):

- Each with their own mean position vectors $(\overline x_1, \overline y_1, \overline z_1)^T$ and $(\overline x_2,\overline y_2,\overline z_2)^T$ respectively,
- Each with their own $3 \times 3$ variance-covariance matrices (**$\Sigma_1$** and **$\Sigma_2 $**) respectively.
- $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$ are independent.

How do I find the variance and covariance of ($\mathbf p_2 - \mathbf p_1$)? In other words, what is the variance and covariance of relative position vector $(\overline x_2 - \overline x_1, \overline y_2 - \overline y_1, \overline z_2 - \overline z_1)^T$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you expand on what you already know yourself? For example, what is the definition of variance and covariance?

Comment: When I said variance, I mean $Var()$ and when I said covariance, I mean $Cov()$

Comment: I am sorry, but that is extremely non-informative. What does $Var()$ mean?

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is not so informative. Sorry for that. Let me rephrase of what I meant.

Variance of relative position vector means the diagonal terms of variance-covariance matrix, while covariance of relative position vector means off-diagonal terms of variance-covariance matrix.

I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: For me this still does not mean anything, because I don't know what the variance-covariance matrix is. This might be general knowledge in your field, I cannot tell.

Comment: May I suggest you to read this article that provide geometric interpretation of the covariance matrix: <http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/>

Comment: For me the link is dead. Moreover, the only thing I wanted to get across is that as currently written, your question is not accessible to a lot of people. I am trying to help you to make your question better. To be honest, there is a reason why I have not read any texts on what the variance-covariance matrix is: I am not that interested in it. Finally, all I needed was:

Answer (score 0):

At least if  $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$ are each multivariate (incl. bivariate) normal, then, as they are independent, you can just sum the covariance matrices to get the covariance matrix of the relative position vector:

$\Sigma_{2-1} = \Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2 $

for the derivation see e.g.:  [Multivariate Normal Difference Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60911/multivariate-normal-difference-distribution)

right now I am not unfortunately not sure about the general case (i.e. other distributions).

Comment: Do you means that I can obtain variance-covariance matrix of relative position vector as follows?
$$\sigma^2_{x_{2-1}} = \sigma^2_{x_2} + \sigma^2_{x_1} $$
$$\sigma^2_{y_{2-1}} = \sigma^2_{y_2} + \sigma^2_{y_1} $$
$$\sigma^2_{z_{2-1}} = \sigma^2_{z_2} + \sigma^2_{z_1} $$

and

$$Cov({x_{2-1}},{y_{2-1}}) = Cov({x_2},{y_2}) + Cov({x_1},{y_1})$$
$$Cov({x_{2-1}},{z_{2-1}}) = Cov({x_2},{z_2}) + Cov({x_1},{z_1})$$
$$Cov({y_{2-1}},{z_{2-1}}) = Cov({y_2},{z_2}) + Cov({y_1},{z_1})$$

Comment: Yes, that's how I have understood it.  If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are each multivariate normal, you can.  For other distributions I'm just not sure at the moment.

Comment: think I missed the title - where it says bivariate, which is a special case of multivariate, so, yes, here you can just sum the covariance matrices.